# Programmatically copy a folder (in a way that mimics a user copy/paste) and update a Progress Bar during the copy?

Tags: vb.net, filesystems, progress-bar, deep-copy

I would like to simulate a folder copy exactly how it would happen if a user copy/pasted it in Windows Explorer (keep all the file/directory attributes, copy all subfolders and files in the same structure, etc.), and be able to update a progress bar during the copy.

`FileSystem.Copy` is a wonderful function that would mimic a user copy/paste, but I am unable to update a progress bar during the copy using that function.

The only way I have found to be able to achieve this is to write a custom function, so the `ProgressBar.Maximum` can be set to the size of the Folder and the `ProgressBar.Value` is updated after each individual file copy.

This function is becoming a lot of code to achieve something that seems simple. I also cannot disregard the notion that since this is customized that I am doing something wrong that I just don't know to test for. For example, had the folder I was testing with not had empty subfolders and hidden folders, I never would have adjusted for those things.

So I have to wonder if I am overlooking something much simpler to achieve this same goal.

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub CopyFolderWithProgress(folderToCopy As String, newFolder As String, progBar As ProgressBar)

    'Validate folder to copy
    If Directory.Exists(folderToCopy) Then
        If folderToCopy.Substring(folderToCopy.Length - 1) <> "\" Then
            folderToCopy &= "\"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid directory given: " & folderToCopy)
        End
    End If

    'Validate new folder
    If Directory.Exists(newFolder) Then
        If newFolder.Substring(newFolder.Length - 1) <> "\" Then
            newFolder &= "\"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid directory given: " & newFolder)
        End
    End If

    'Create folderToCopy as a new subfolder of newFolder
    newFolder &= New DirectoryInfo(folderToCopy).Name & "\"
    Dim di As DirectoryInfo
    di = Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolder)
    di.Attributes = New DirectoryInfo(folderToCopy).Attributes

    'Create all subfolders
    For Each thisDir In Directory.GetDirectories(folderToCopy, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        Dim thisDirRelative = thisDir.Remove(0, Len(folderToCopy))

        di = Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolder & thisDirRelative)
        di.Attributes = New DirectoryInfo(thisDir).Attributes
    Next

    'Determine size of all files for progress bar
    Dim dirSize As Long
    For Each curFile In Directory.GetFiles(folderToCopy, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        dirSize += FileLen(curFile)
    Next

    'Set progress bar 100% to size of all files
    progBar.Value = 0
    progBar.Maximum = dirSize

    'Copy all files into correct folder and update progress bar
    For Each curFile In Directory.GetFiles(folderToCopy, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        'Get name of file
        Dim curFileName = Path.GetFileName(curFile)

        'Determine if file is in a subfolder of fileTopCopy
        Dim curFileDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(curFile) + "\"
        Dim curFileSubfolders = curFile.Substring(0, curFile.IndexOf(curFileName)).Replace(folderToCopy, "")

        'Copy file
        If File.Exists(curFile) Then
            File.Copy(curFile, newFolder & curFileSubfolders & curFileName)
        Else
            Console.Write("Issue copying a file that should exist in source folder: " & curFile)
        End If

        'Update Progress Bar
        progBar.Value += FileLen(curFile)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory`, which actually uses the same functionality as the Windows shell and will provide the progress bar for you.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you, this is great peace of mind that the functionality matches. I do wish that there was  a way to report to an actual `ProgressBar` winforms control, as every other action of my app reports to a `ProgressBar`